# read android folder only till 5 sub folder

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-studio

i have code which read every folder and try to read mp3 files in mobile. but issue is, it going for each and every sub folder in device and its taking hug time. What i want. i want to limit my search condition till 5 sub folder. Mean folder and till 3 sub folders. like
    /Storage/sdcard0/
/Storage/sdcard0/Android/
/Storage/sdcard0/Android/data/

after this folder it need to check for next folder. i.e
/Storage/sdcard0/download

here my code.

```
int folderno = 0;

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(String rootPath) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> fileList = new ArrayList<>();


    try {
        File rootFolder = new File(rootPath);
        File[] files = rootFolder.listFiles(); //here you will get NPE if directory doesn't contains  any file,handle it like this.
        for (File file : files) {
            if (folderno <3 && file.isDirectory()) {
                folderno = folderno + 1;

                if (getPlayList(file.getAbsolutePath()) != null) {

                    fileList.addAll(getPlayList(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                } else {
                    folderno = 0;
                    //break;
                }
            } else if (file.getName().endsWith(".mp3")) {



                // folderno = folderno - 1;
                HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<>();
                song.put("file_path", file.getAbsolutePath());
                song.put("file_name", file.getName());
                fileList.add(song);
            }
        }
        folderno = 0;
        return fileList;
    } catch (Exception e) {

        return null;
    }
}
```

i tried to include some logic but its now working. I created folderno as a variable and checking that. 
Thank you in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this in eclipse

```
private int count = 0;
private void readFiveDir(File file) {
    count++;
    System.out.println("Directory/File Name : " + file.getName());
    System.out.println("Folder No : " + count);
    if(file.isDirectory()) {
        if(count == 5) {
            return;
        }
        for(File currFile : file.listFiles()) {
            readFiveDir(currFile);
        }
    }
}
```

My directory structure :

[image: Directory Structure]

```
Output :

Directory/File Name : Dir1
Folder No : 1
Directory/File Name : Dir2
Folder No : 2
Directory/File Name : Dir3
Folder No : 3
Directory/File Name : Dir4
Folder No : 4
Directory/File Name : Dir5
Folder No : 5
Directory/File Name : Dir5a
Folder No : 6
Directory/File Name : Dir5a_1
Folder No : 7
Directory/File Name : Dir5a_2
Folder No : 8
Directory/File Name : Dir5b
Folder No : 9
Directory/File Name : Dir5b_1
Folder No : 10
Directory/File Name : Dir5b_2
Folder No : 11
Directory/File Name : Dir2a
Folder No : 12
Directory/File Name : Dir2b
Folder No : 13
```

Try it and let me know.